# Let $S = \{1/n, n \in\mathbb N\}$ and we define a function $f : \{0\} \cup S \to \mathbb R$ as the formula below. is this function continuous at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

the function is $f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(\pi/x)  & \text{ if } x\neq0 \\
                                         0     & \text{ if } x=0 \end{cases}$

I know that that it is proven using the definition of continuity at a point however, I do not know how to go about it.

Comment: It is continuous since the function is just the $0$ function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Don Thousand says, realize that

$$
\forall x\in S:\ 
f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)= \sin(n \pi)=0
$$

for some $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$. On the other hand, $f(0)=0$. Therefore $f(x)=0$ at every point of its domain, so it is constant, hence continuous everywhere, including at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is continuous, since your function is constant because $sin(\pi \cdot n)=0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. A more interesting question is what about the function with same domain $S \cup \{0\}$ but $f(x)= sin(\pi/2x)$? (hint: it's not more continuous; use sequence criterion to obtain a contradiction around $0$)